# Extract Year/Month/Day from string

Tags: php, regex

How can I extract the date in the following string:

```
"Hästebäck 1960-03-13"
```

I want to extract 1960-03-13.

Comment: No need of regex. Use `explode(' ', $input)`

Comment: [Simple `\S+$` will give you the result.](http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/35)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `date_parse` function as well

```
$string = "Hästebäck 1960-03-13";
$result = date_parse($string);
print_r($result);
```

it will return you  an array like this

```
Array ( [year] => 1960 [month] => 3 [day] => 13 [hour] => [minute] => [second] => [fraction] ..........
```

you can use date like this

```
echo $result['year'].'-'.$result['month'].'-'.$result['day'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try PHP `explode.`

```
<?php

$string = "Hästebäck 1960-03-13";
$array = explode(" ",$string);
echo $array[1];
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/aTsnZ0)**

Answer (score 0):

```
([\d-]+)
```

This should do it.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/34

Edit:to get year month separately try

```
(\d+?)(?=-|$)
```

See demo

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/37

Comment: Thank you. I have an array with the string rows like in my question. I want to extract the year, month and the date from this string in the array. You can find my code here: http://pastebin.com/uZVk0muz The problem is that I don't get the date-part, I only get this: http://pastebin.com/H9TPHWx8 I want to extract the date-part and then assign it elsewhere.

Comment: @user500468 try this (\d+?)(?=-|$)

Comment: Now I get this: Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '(' in /var/www/curl3.php on line 260